# scheduled job on play using akka

Tags: playframework-2.0, akka

i am trying to execute a method every minute using akka. although i am getting no errors but the method is never executed!!
i tried to extend play.api.globalsettings but i got an error for that. so i implemented it.

here is my code:

```
public class Global implements play.api.GlobalSettings {

    ActorRef tickActor;

    @Override
    public void beforeStart(Application app) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(play.api.Application app) {
        {

        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS),
                Duration.create(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
                new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Secured securedObject = new Secured();
                        securedObject.deleteExpiredTokensAndUsers();
                    }
                },
                Akka.system().dispatcher()
        );

    }
```

any idea?

Answer (score 2):

In a java application you should extend from play.GlobalSettings and not play.**api**.GlobalSettings

In Play Framework 2 for a Java application you should use the framework's play package, and for a Scala application you use the play.api package. They may have a lot of classes in common but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

thanks dribba, got it solved.  here is my code:

```
import controllers.Secured;
import play.Application;
import play.GlobalSettings;
import play.libs.Akka;
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 4/3/14.
 */
public class Global extends GlobalSettings {
    @Override
    public void onStart(Application application) {

        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.create(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
                Duration.create(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Secured.deleteExpiredTokensAndUsers();
                    }
                },
                Akka.system().dispatcher()

        );
    }
}
```